# How can we change the logo in Laravel Nova4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

What is the way to change the logo in Laravel Nova4?
I have checked the document but I can not find the way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To customize or change logo in laravel nova version 4, you need to define logo path in your app/config/nova.php file like this

```
'brand' => [
    'logo' => 'images/logo.svg' // What ever your logo path in your project
],
```

Comment: And it looks like only svg logo images are allowed by laravel nova version 4, other image formats are not supported

Comment: Yes, Pratik is right, SVG is seems to be required, see my answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

use SVG: I have not been able to get any other image file type to work. This will work (note I used the public_path function to get me into the right place):

```
     'logo' => public_path('images/robLogo/logoLargerFinal.svg'),
```